# In Fixed Header Uncaught TypeError top undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm doing fixed header after window scroll header should be fixed on top
I keep getting following error,

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined

Here what might be the problem, can anyone solve this?

HTML:

```
    <header id="masthead" class="site-header is-sticky">
    <div class="header-box">        
        <div class="header-left">
            <div class="logo">
                <a href="#" title="" alt="">
                    <img src="images/logo-dark.png">
                </a>
            </div><!-- .logo-->
        </div><!-- .header-left-->

        <div class="header-right">
            <div class="primary-menu">
                <ul class="sf-menu">
                    <li class="current"><a href="#">Headers</a>
                        <ul>
                            <li><a href="Fixed-header.html">Fixed header</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li><a href="#">About Us</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Contact Us</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div><!--primary menu-->
        </div><!-- .header-right-->
    </div><!-- .is-sticky-->
</header>
```

code :

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
 var num = $('.site-header.is-sticky').offset().top;
    $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
            $('.site-header.is-sticky').addClass('fixed-header');
            $('.logo').css({'padding':'5px 0'});
            $('.logo img').css({'transform':'scale(0.70)','transition':'all .3s ease-out','transform-origin':'left'});
            $('.topbar-wrap').hide();
        }
        else {
            num = $('.site-header.is-sticky').offset().top;
            $('.site-header.is-sticky').removeClass('fixed-header');
            $('.logo').css({'padding':'20px 0'});
            $('.logo img').css({'transform':'scale(1)'});
            $('.topbar-wrap').show();
        }
    });
```

Comment: please share the DOM

Comment: Can you please post the header HTML.

Comment: Possible Duplicate of [Why does jQuery or a DOM method such as getElementById not find the element?](//stackoverflow.com/q/14028959)

Comment: `$('.site-header , .is-sticky').offset().top` I think you dont have the dom element with classes  `site-header and is-sticky`. So its not finding the element. use `.site-header , .is-sticky` so it will find the DOM element having the class either of this.

Comment: @Tushar yeah maybe its duplicate but in my code I unable to solve this problem.

Comment: @Husna Where is the script included? in `<head>`? Wrap the code in `ready` and try. Let me know if this work

Comment: i added but not working.i think need to write if()

Comment: Looks like the selector is incorrect. Add corresponding HTML code in the question.

Comment: @Tushar I edited my question check once.

Comment: @Tushar those are adjoining classes.

Comment: Your code is working fine. https://jsfiddle.net/hneg5km2/

Comment: @ Suresh Ponnukalai the same page not getting this error when i move in other page getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot find the DOM element using the given jquery, hence to error.

My guess is that getting the element by the class just doesn't find it, so switch to ID and it will sort out:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){ 
 var num = $('#masthead').offset().top;
    $(window).bind('scroll', function() {
        if ($(window).scrollTop() > num) {
            $('.site-header.is-sticky').addClass('fixed-header');
            $('.logo').css({'padding':'5px 0'});
            $('.logo img').css({'transform':'scale(0.70)','transition':'all .3s ease-out','transform-origin':'left'});
            $('.topbar-wrap').hide();
        }
        else {
            num = $('.site-header.is-sticky').offset().top;
            $('.site-header.is-sticky').removeClass('fixed-header');
            $('.logo').css({'padding':'20px 0'});
            $('.logo img').css({'transform':'scale(1)'});
            $('.topbar-wrap').show();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can call DOM element by this way:
 var num = $('.site-header.is-sticky:first-of-type').offset().top;

Comment: the same page not getting this error when i move to other page getting this error.

Comment: If you have more that one objects class .site-header.is-sticky you can use
$('.site-header.is-sticky').each(function (){
num = $(this)..offset().top;
});

Comment: now I'm getting num is not define. if ($(window).scrollTop() > num)